# error in uploading the image to the upload folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been trying to get this to work since this morning, but have no idea why it doesn't. The uploaded image gets stored in the database, but when I check my upload folder --where I want to store the images -- there's nothing there.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Home.php

```
    <?php  
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

    class Home extends CI_Controller {  

        public function __construct() 
        {
            parent::__construct();

            //load database libray manually
            $this->load->database();

            //load Model
            $this->load->model('Contact_model');

            // load form and url helpers
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

            // load form_validation library
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
        }

         public function Latest_news()
        {  
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_content', 'First content', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('second_content', 'Second content', 'required');
            $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if (($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE )&&(!$this->upload->do_upload('filename')))
            {
                $this->load->view('Latest_news'); 
            }
            else
            {
                //insert
                $data = array();
                $data['first_content']=$this->input->post('first_content');
                $data['second_content']=$this->input->post('second_content');
                $data['filename']=$this->input->post('filename');  
                //Transfering data to Model
                $this->Contact_model->latest_news($data);
                //Redirecting to success page
                redirect(site_url('Home/Latest_news'));
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Contact_model.php

```
    <?php
        class Contact_model extends CI_Model 
        {
            function latest_news($data)
            {
            //saving records
            $this->db->insert('latest_news', $data); 
            }

        }   
    ?>
```

Latest_news.php

```
    <?php echo form_open(); ?>
        <div style="padding-top:10%; padding-left:30%">
            <div>
                <textarea name="first_content" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                <span><?php echo form_error("first_content");?></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <textarea name="second_content" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                <span><?php echo form_error("second_content");?></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="file" name="filename">
                <span><?php echo form_error("filename");?></span>
            </div><br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Make sure that you have `error_reporting()` turned on and, while you develop, have `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` so that you get any error messages (like invalid upload path/wrong permissions and such).

Comment: If you are going to else then it mean your `$this->upload->do_upload('filename')` is not working.

Comment: @urfusion - There's a `!` in front of that call so it will always goes to the `else`-block unless both the validation fails and the upload fails.

Comment: so what can i do sir please help me

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : yes, which should not be there. as if all validation are passed and there is error in upload then it should show the error not keep the flow going.

Comment: The `!` should probably stay, but the `&&` should probably be a `||`

Comment: sir my problem is the uploaded imge is not getting stored in the upload folder that is my isue

Comment: Are you using Linux or window system? check for permissions.

Comment: Did you turn on error reporting and display errors? Did you get any error messages? Have you checked the servers error log? We can't really help you if you don't give us any feedback on our suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use function **form_open_multipart()** in Latest_news.php instead **form_open()**

Comment: can try to specify the full path to the directory instead of  './uploads/э and set its permissions to 775

Comment: full path in the sence i did not got u sir

Comment: and what is 775 permission ?

Comment: sir i just need little guidence sir, the image which im trying to uplaod its getting stored in the database but not in folder means, what might be the issue sir.